# Dart List within a Map

Tags: dart

I have a Map in Dart (originally loaded from JSON) that looks something like this:

```
somevar = {
    'Title': 'Some object',
    'items': [{'title': 'Item 1 Title'}, {'title': 'Item 2 Title'}]
}
```

For some reason `somevar['items']` doesn't behave quite like a list.
I get `Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'iterator'` if I attempt to iterate over the list.

I also get a similar error if I try `somevar['items'].length`

If I manually load this "list" like this: `someList = new List(somevar['items']);` then it works as expected.

Any idea why this is that case, and what I'm doing wrong? For me the natural expectation would be that a "list" parsed from JSON will behave exactly like the List() object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, seems that I had a deeper issue in my code that cause my `somevar` variable to be null (even though it should have the map.
Anyway, I'm marking this as solved for now so not to waste anyone's time.